# Regex to test for restricted word in email address not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have a regular expression that is giving me some trouble.    I want to restrict domains that have a certain word in them, such as 'foobar'.    I have a regex to test for a certain domain, such as foobar.com, but I also want to cover:

- internal.foobar.com
- foobarcorp.com
- randomdomainwithfoobarinit.co.uk
- foobar.net
- Etc

So far my regex, covers almost everything correctly, except if there are characters before `foobar`   so `myfoobar.com` would not be caught, but `foobarcorp.com` would.    I have tried a mix of `w+` and `.` and `*` after the `@` sign with no luck finding the right combo.   Any ideas?   I tried to search around stack overflow, but most of the similar questions cover restricting a certain, already known domain where I am trying to cover domains I don't necessarily know about ahead of time.

**Code:**

```
var regex = /\w+@((?!foobar).)*\../i;
ngModel.$setValidity('restrict-email', regex.test(value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var regex = /\w+@(\w+\.?)?foobar(\w+)?(\.\w+)+/i;

console.log(regex.test('a@internal.foobar.com'));
console.log(regex.test('a@foobarcorp.com'));
console.log(regex.test('a@foobarcorp.com'));
console.log(regex.test('a@randomdomainwithfoobarinit.co.uk'));
console.log(regex.test('a@foobar.net'));
```

Comment: I had to add in support for a optional dash `?(-)` before and after foobar, but this got to me the promised land, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

`/.*(foobar).*/i`

I tested it on RegExr and it matched all the cases you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
\w+@?((?!foobar).)*\.
```

Just missing an `optional` parameter `?`

To be more specific you can list the domains out yourself like so:

```
\w+@?((?!foobar).)*\.(com|net|co\.uk)
```

https://regexr.com/3h68s

But that's obviously a decision you can make based on the security you're looking to offer.